# Extract values with stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, gaps-and-islands

I need your help to create a view in SQL Server (v12.0.6024.0). One of my customer has a table in which some time slot are saved in this format:

| ID | ID_EVENT | Time Slot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 24 | 08:30:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 09:00:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 09:30:00.0000 |

Every time slot lasts 30 minutes, the example above means that event with ID 24 (saved in another table) lasted form 8:30 to 10:00 (3rd slot started at 9:30, lasted 30 minutes so it finished at 10:00). The problem is that in some cases the time values are not consecutive and there may be a pause in the middle, so I would have something like this:

| ID | ID_EVENT | Time Slot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 24 | 08:30:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 09:00:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 09:30:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 11:30:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 12:00:00.0000 |
| 1000 | 24 | 12:30:00.0000 |

In this case event with ID 24 lasted from 8:30 to 10, stopped, then started again from 11:30 to 13:00. I have been asked to prepare a view for an external developer in which I have to report not only the time the event started (in my example, 8:30) and the time it stopped for good (in my example 13:00) but also the time the pause started (in my example 10:00) and the time the pause finished (in my example 11:30).

I have no problem with the first 2 values but I don't know how to extract the other two. I think we can consider a pause happening when 2 time slots are not consecutive, there cannot be more than periods for the same event. I suppose I need a procedure but find it difficult to write it; I need to have a view that says

| ID | ID_EVENT | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 24 | 08:30:00.0000 | 10:00:00.0000 | 11:30:00.0000 | 13:00:00.0000 |

Any help?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What happens if there are 2 "pauses"; are you expecting 6 time columns? If there are 4, are you expecting 10 time columns? If so, then you can't do this in a `VIEW`.

Comment: Also, your title says "storied" procedure (I assume you mean Stored Procedure), but everything in your question talks about a `VIEW`. A `VIEW` and a `PROCEDURE` are *very* different object types. What are you *actually* after?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I have to prepare a View; I supposed I need to write a procedure to call in the query to extract the 2 missing fields. In any case, I will never have 2 pauses, every process will consist of either one or two intervals of time. As for the title, I obviously meant "Stored", storied was a typo.

Comment: But if you want a Stored procedure, why is everything in your question about a `VIEW`? Like I said, a `VIEW` and `PROCEDURE` are *very* different object types. What are you *actually* after?

Comment: I need to write a View. It would be great if I can prepare this view without using any procedure but I am not sure it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t table(ID int, ID_EVENT int, TimeSlot time)
insert into @t
values
(1000,  24, '08:30:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '09:00:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '09:30:00.0000'),
--
(1000,  24, '11:30:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '12:00:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '12:30:00.0000'),
--
(1000,  24, '15:00:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '15:30:00.0000'),
(1000,  24, '16:00:00.0000'),
--
(1000,  25, '15:30:00.0000'),
(1000,  25, '16:30:00.0000');


select Id, ID_EVENT, 
    min(TimeSlot) as StartTimeSlot, 
    dateadd(minute, 30, max(TimeSlot)) as EndTimeSlot
from 
(
    select *,
    datediff(minute, '00:00:00', Timeslot)/30 - row_number() over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT order by TimeSlot) as grpid
    from @t
) as t
group by Id, ID_EVENT, grpid;



--first two groups per event&id row
select Id, ID_EVENT,
--1
min(case when grpordinal = 1 then TimeSlot end) as StartSlot1,
dateadd(minute, 30, max(case when grpordinal = 1 then TimeSlot end)) as EndSlot1,
--2
min(case when grpordinal = 2 then TimeSlot end) as StartSlot2,
dateadd(minute, 30, max(case when grpordinal = 2 then TimeSlot end)) as EndSlot2
from 
(
    select Id, ID_EVENT, TimeSlot,
        dense_rank() over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT order by grpid) as grpordinal
    from 
    (
        select *,
        datediff(minute, '00:00:00', Timeslot)/30 - row_number() over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT order by TimeSlot) as grpid
        from @t
    ) as t
) as src
--where grpordinal <= 2 --not really needed
group by Id, ID_EVENT;



--!!!!only when there are max two groups/periods
--if there could be more than 2 periods this will not work
select Id, ID_EVENT,
--1
min(case when grpid = 0 then TimeSlot end) as StartSlot1,
dateadd(minute, 30, max(case when grpid = 0 then TimeSlot end)) as EndSlot1,
--2
min(case when grpid <> 0 then TimeSlot end) as StartSlot2,
dateadd(minute, 30, max(case when grpid <> 0 then TimeSlot end)) as EndSlot2
from
(
select *,
/*
    1
    + datediff(minute, '00:00:00', Timeslot)/30 - row_number() over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT order by TimeSlot) 
    - datediff(minute, '00:00:00', min(Timeslot) over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT)) /30
*/
    1
    + datediff(minute, min(Timeslot) over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT), TimeSlot)/30  
    - row_number() over(partition by Id, ID_EVENT order by TimeSlot)
    as grpid --1st groupid is always 0
from @t
) as t
group by Id, ID_EVENT;
```

Comment: thank you for your help @Iptr but there is something wrong, I get 2 rows instead of 1 for ID_Event 25

Comment: ...@SCdev... the diff between the two rows (of id_event=25) is more than 30mins..thus the two rows are not consecutive and they belong to (two) different groups.

Comment: My bad @lptr, you are right, I didn't notice that. Sorry!

Comment: ..@SCdev .. no problem.. what is missing here, from your question? --> `there cannot be more than periods for the same event.`  ..there can only be 2 periods, and you would rather have them (2 periods) next to each other, as 4 columns, for one event row?

Comment: yes @Iptr, I need to end up with all the times in one row. If the event consists of only one interval, 2 column will be empty or NULL , if it has 2 periods I would have values in all the 4 columns

Comment: ..@SCdev.. answer's been edited. dense_rank() is not actually needed if there can be 2 periods max...the 2 groups could be identified by dividing grpid with (datediff(minute, '00:00:00', min(Timeslot) over(partition by ID, ID_EVENT))/30)..then the first grp woud be 0 and the other would be <> 0 and you could use that in the conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to identify and group together "adjacent" time slots.

I would suggest putting the ranges in rows rather than in column. For this, you can use window functions like that:

```
select id, id_event, 
    min(timeslot) as timeslot_start, max(timeslot) as timeslot_end
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id, id_event order by timeslot) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, id_event, datediff(minute, - rn * 30, timeslot)
```

If want to see the first two ranges per event only - both on the same row in the resultset - then we can use conditional aggregation on top of that query:

```
select id, id_event,
    max(case when rn = 1 then timeslot_start end) as timeslot_start_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then timeslot_end   end) as timeslot_end_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then timeslot_start end) as timeslot_start_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then timeslot_end   end) as timeslot_end_2
from (
    select id, id_event, 
        min(timeslot) as timeslot_start, max(timeslot) as timeslot_end,
        row_number() over(partition by id, id_event order by min(timeslot)) rn
    from (
        select t.*, 
            row_number() over(partition by id, id_event order by timeslot) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by id, id_event, datediff(minute, - rn * 30, timeslot)
) t
where rn <= 2
group by id, id_event
```